# How can I get Gigabit network?

Tags: networking, gigabit-ethernet

I'm using an XFX 750I motherboard and a D-link DWR-112 router to connect to my network. It is showing that it's using 100 Mbps when connected through above mentioned motherboard's Ethernet port.

Can I get 1000 Mbps i.e. 1 Gbps networking speed in my local area network? If so, how?

Comment: When you say `is showing...100 Mbps` what is "it"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manual of the D-Link DWR-112 mentions that it uses four 10/100 Base-TX ports.

That means you can use this switch for 10 Mbit or 100 Mbit connection, but not for 1000 Mbit. If you want faster local connection then you will need another device.

For example, buy a Gigabit capable switch, connect everything to that switch. If you are using the USB port on the DWR-112 then leave it in the network, connected with one cable to the new switch.

Comment: do I need to change my router only or I too will have to change my motherbaord to get 1000 mbps networking. can you suggest me which dlink router am I supposed to purchase for 1gbps??

Comment: @kashif You do not need to change your motherboard. Your motherboard supports gigabit speeds, and should be fine.

Comment: thanks brother and what about the cable.. should it be cat6 or even cat5 will work for 1gbps???

Comment: Cat 5E and cat6 cables will work guaranteed. Lower quality cable (e.g. plain old cat5) usually works fine when used in regular home situations.  Just do not try to run 100 meter long cat5 cables at gigabit speeds.

Comment: cat5 is not rated for gigabit, only cat5e and up, it will hinder any attempt at gigabit speeds if used.

Answer (score 3):

I took a look at the specifications of your motherboard and router, and the problem is because your router's ethernet ports only support speeds of up to 100Mbps.

On the second page of the [spec sheet](http://global.dlink.com.sg/site_pdtpdfs/DWR-112/DWR-112_ds.pdf), it says: *RJ-45 10/100BASE-TX Ethernet Ports*.

You will need a router with 10/100/1000BASE-T ports to get Gigabit speeds. I would also recommend CAT-6 Ethernet cables if you're transmitting over any significant distance.

Comment: thanks. means problem is with my router not with my motherboard. right???/

Comment: That is correct. Your motherboard supports Gigabit speeds.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like that's a gigabit router, based on the [manual](ftp://dlinkmea.com/ftp/pdfs/products/DWR-112/DWR-112_ds.pdf). You will need a router with gigabit support to get gigabit speeds.